# Smooth functions which attain rational values on rationals

Tags: real-analysis

I'm interested in functions $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ with the additional property $f(\mathbb Q) \subseteq \mathbb Q$. The only examples I came up with are polynomials with rational coefficients. Is this all?

Comment: You can certainly also get (suitable) quotients of polynomials with rational coefficients

Comment: Consider sequences with $(f_n) \in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ (all $f_n$ compactly supported on a same compact) with $f_0=f$ arbitrary and  $f_n(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n!}) \subset \mathbb{Q}$. This last restriction doesn't forbid $\|f_n^{(k)}-f_{n+1}^{(k)}\|_\infty$ to be arbitrary small for $k \le n$, in particular the sequence can be chosen to converge in $C^k$ for every $k$, thus the limit is $C^\infty$ and maps $\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}$. RobertIsrael has an answer somewhere showing the same works for $f_n$ real or complex analytic.

Comment: @nobody: Sure, if the denominator has no real roots. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Anything unclear ?

Comment: @reuns: Are you implying that a converging sequence of rational numbers has a rational number as limit?

Comment: Of course no, the idea is to modify at each $n$ the image of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n!} \setminus \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(n-1)!}$